# Is there any advantage to the PIMP-Boy 3 Billion?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I just got a PIMP-Boy 3 Billion. Aside from the fact that it looks a little cooler, if really gaudy, is there any advantage to using it instead of my old PIP-Boy 3000, or vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It Looks Awesome.

---

That is the only advantage.

Comment: I want to say that I read somewhere that the flashlight feature for the PIMP-Boy was *slightly* brighter, but I can't find that documentation anywhere now.....